# i18next cannot find key

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I installed i18next in my react app. Removed backend part of i18next as I dont need it.
Then created a file at this path:
public/locales/en/translation.json

That file contains this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1en"
}
```

Previously I created this file according to docs:

```
src/i18n.js
```

Containing this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
});
export default i18n;
```

While in src/index.js I added:

```
import './i18n';
```

Now from one of my view, I import it this way:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
const Index = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

    return(
        <h1>{t('key1')}</h1>
    )
```

What I see in the console is this message:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation key1 key1
```

And on the page I only see the text "key1", obviously.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include en file in the init

```
import translation from  "path_to_file/translation.json"

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translation,
  },
};


i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },         
    lng: "en",

});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ja8tb?file=src%2Fi18n.js,src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js)

Comment: is this really the way to go? Translation file is besides in public folder and thus not accessible from i18next. I tried to create a folder inside src. Not working. But as I said, is this really the way to go?

Comment: Yes. you need to move the translation file under src.  we need to attach the en file in the init function so that react would know where to look the translations.

Comment: Inside "i18n.js" I added this: "import translation from  "./locales/en/translation.json";". While in the init-function I added this: en:{translation: translation},lng: "en". Looking into the console I see debug info. It says: "i18next: initialized". And I see the entry "en.translation" that contains "key1: value1en". However, I still see the message "i18next::translator: missingKey en translation key1 key1". Interesting that the word "key1" is shown twice in the message. From the view Im calling it like this: "{t('key1')}"

Comment: see the update OP

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways on how translations can be loaded.
Please check the [official documentation](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations).

- adding resources on init
- after init
- via backend plugin